# Laravel Nova : Avatar Fields using S3 disk but return 0 value

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-nova, laravel-filesystem

i try to upload avatar photo on my user model, using laravel nova Fields\Avatar applying the simpliest code, but it return `0` value on my database, the disk already set to `s3` disk in filesystem also nova disk. is it something missing or i skip some of process?

oh and by the way, i already installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3. but not resolve it at all.

here's my code :

my nova.php config

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Nova Storage Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This configuration option allows you to define the default disk that
    | will be used to store files using the Image, File, and other file
    | related field types. You're welcome to use any configured disk.
    |
     */

    'storage_disk' => env('NOVA_STORAGE_DISK', 's3'),
```

my filesystems.php config

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
    |
    */

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DISK', 's3'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been set up for each driver as an example of the required values.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [
        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Symbolic Links
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the symbolic links that will be created when the
    | `storage:link` Artisan command is executed. The array keys should be
    | the locations of the links and the values should be their targets.
    |
    */

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

];
```

my resource fields nova

```
/**
     * Get the fields displayed by the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function fields(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return [
            Fields\Avatar::make('Avatar'),
            Fields\Text::make('Name')->sortable()->rules(['required']),
            Fields\Email::make('Email')->rules(['required', 'email']),
            Fields\Text::make('Phone')->rules(['required']),

            (new Panel('Job Position', $this->jobFields()))->limit(3),
            (new Panel('Employee Information', $this->employeeFields()))->limit(2),
            (new Panel('Payroll Information', $this->payrollFields()))->limit(2),
            (new Panel('Date Information', $this->dateFields())),
            (new Panel('Authentication', $this->authenticationFields())),
        ];
    }
```

i excpected the outcome of avatar fields is returning the asset that i upload on my s3 disk, but it happen like this

[the preview of my avatar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSrwU.png)

[the database value on `avatar` column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emFEu.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved guys, i just forget to set `true` of `throw` key on my filesystems.php :D

the actual error appear suddenly.

this config that i forget :

```
    's3' => [
                'driver' => 's3',
                'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
                'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
                'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
                'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
                'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
                'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
                'visibility' => 'public',
                'throw' => true // <- this line has to be true for debugging
            ],
```